# where to set the language specific name of an ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, publish

I am confused with all the namings of my App in Xcode, ITunes , Build-Settings->"Product Name" AppID and so on.

Where in the end I will set the name (per language) ?
Is this name the same : "under the appicon" and displayed in AppleStore ?

**update**

I just found out, that this is done with InfoPlist.strings and the value for "CFBundleDisplayName" which can be assigned to languages. But I don't know how to handle these files. Do I copy these files in "finder" or is there a gui/process doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an emtpy file "InfoPlist.strings" in the same folder that contains your "Localizable.strings" files.
2. Select the file in the Project navigator and open the File inspector in the Utilities View (the window on the right side in Xcode).
3. Tap the button "Localize..." in the "Localization" section and select your base language.
4. The button disappears from the "Localization" and you can now select the languages that you want to localize.
5. The "InfoPlist.strings" file now has a subfile for each language you selected (like the "Localizable.strings" file also have). In each subfile add `CFBundleDisplayName = "LOCALIZED_APP_NAME";`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this also the same name , which we can see in AppleStore, when published ?

Comment: You add the App name that is displayed in the App Store when you upload your binary (when you also add the description and screenshots). So, no, this is not the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.